# Text Not showing on second line inside column -Flutter

Tags: flutter, text

I am struggling to show long text which is an address in string format. And it can take one or two or more lines, i have tried every solution to show text completely but every time it overflows.  I have used flexible, expandable and all text properties like soft wrap but it is not working. I have to show this column inside ListTile.

```
showPickedDropoffLocations() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
          .start, //meant to align elements to the left - seems to be working
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.pin_drop,
                color: Colors.pink,
                size: 24.0,
                
              ),
              Text("Pickup Location"),
            ]),

        Container(
            height: 50,
            
            child: Text(pickedAddress, style: TextStyle(), softWrap: true)),
        

        Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('.'),
              Text('.'),
              Text('.'),
            
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 5),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.pin_drop,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 24.0,
                
              ),
              Text("DropOff Location"),
            ]),
        
        Container(
            
            child: Text(dropOffAddress, style: TextStyle(), softWrap: true)),
      ],
    );
  }
```

When i try to use **flexible** this error occurs

```
Error 
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 2343): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 2343): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter ( 2343): When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint, for example if it is in a     
I/flutter ( 2343): horizontal scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a      
I/flutter ( 2343): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter ( 2343): space in the horizontal direction.
I/flutter ( 2343): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter ( 2343): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter ( 2343): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter ( 2343): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter ( 2343): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter ( 2343): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum      
I/flutter ( 2343): constraints provided by the parent.
I/flutter ( 2343): If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
I/flutter ( 2343):   https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
I/flutter ( 2343):   http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
I/flutter ( 2343): The affected RenderFlex is:
I/flutter ( 2343):   RenderFlex#7501a relayoutBoundary=up21 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: 
Row ← Column ← Row ← Container ← Column ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _ListTile ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← Semantics ← ⋯, parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained), size: MISSING, direction: horizontal, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: center, textDirection: ltr, verticalDirection: down)
I/flutter ( 2343): The creator information is set to:
I/flutter ( 2343):   Row ← Column ← Row ← Container ← Column ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _ListTile      
I/flutter ( 2343):   ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← Semantics ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 2343): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: RenderFlex#0f869 relayoutBoundary=up19 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
I/flutter ( 2343):   creator: Row ← Container ← Column ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _ListTile ←
I/flutter ( 2343):     MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 2343):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
I/flutter ( 2343):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=295.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 2343):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 2343):   direction: horizontal
I/flutter ( 2343):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 2343):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 2343):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 2343):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter ( 2343):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 2343): See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
I/flutter ( 2343): If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
I/flutter ( 2343):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 2343):
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap your `Text` Widget with `Flexible` widget.

```dart
Flexible(
child:Text("Your very very long text"),
),
```

Comment: please check error, it happens when i add flexible

Answer (score 1):

Put the `Text` widget in the `Expanded` widget

```
   Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.pin_drop,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 24.0,
          ),
          Expanded( // <-- add this widget here
              child: Text( // <-- Text widget here
                  "Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a documenta seaw")),
        ]),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  child: Text(pickedAddress, maxLines: 4,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,),
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29591700)

Comment: @xdeepakv: In what way is this not an answer? It could use an explanation. And it may be wrong (I’m not sure). But, if so, those are reasons to downvote it, not delete it. It still proposes an answer.

Answer (score -1):

you need to  use \n for next line.

For example:
String address = 'My text address.\nThis line wraps to the next.\nAnother line.';